Is it possible to know last time a Row was updated in a table or view in Snowflake?
I’m working on an implementation of a view in Snowflake. I want to know when was the last time that a single row was updated. Is there a column from Snowflake or maybe a way to do that?
For example. I have a user table with ID and NAME columns and a row just like this:
ID = 1
NAME = Allan

If I update the name from Allan to Juan I would like to know exactly when that happened for that row. There is a way to do that in the view?
I would like to add that "last update" column as a part of the view.

no is the answer, if you want to track row change time, you should implement a updated_timestamp on your updates. Given rows are columns in a partition files, if the partion write time (it is imutable) it would be possible to know the row had no been updated  later than the partiton write time. But that is not accessible. Also for short term, Streams can track changes. But it seems you just need/want to track it yourself.

Row level modification timestamp is not available in the information_schema views currently.
However, there is a column LAST_ALTERED in the SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.TABLES view that gives the Date and time when the table was last altered by a DDL or DML operation.
For the specific requirement you have shared as part of the example, you may consider implementing a stream.
Standard stream (also known as Delta stream) should do. The catch with Standard streams is it performs a join on inserted and deleted rows in the change set to provide the row level delta. As a net effect, for example, a row that is inserted and then deleted between two transactional points of time in a table is removed in the delta (i.e. is not returned when the stream is queried).
If there is a requirement to track each and every single modification to every row, then we could consider implementing a combination of two streams - a Standard stream and an Append Only stream.
An append-only stream exclusively tracks row inserts. Update, delete, and truncate operations are not captured by append-only streams. For instance, if 10 rows are initially inserted into a table, and then 5 of those rows are deleted before advancing the offset for an append-only stream, the stream would only record the 10 inserted rows.
Reference: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/streams-intro

@SimeonPilgrim appears to have the correct answer but it may also be worthwhile adding an UPDATED_BY, INSERTED_TIMESTAMP as well as the UPDATED_TIMESTAMP columns so you can better track changes in your table as is standard practice in S&P IHS Markit EDM (formerly CADIS) (ETL package used in financial services).
Something like this:
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE T_EMPLOYEE(
    EMPLOYEE_ID INTEGER,
    TITLE VARCHAR(50),
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(100),
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR(100),
    SALARY DECIMAL(10, 2),
    INSERTED_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
    UPDATED_TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
    UPDATED_BY VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT CURRENT_USER()
    );

INSERT INTO T_EMPLOYEE (EMPLOYEE_ID, TITLE, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, SALARY)
VALUES (1, 'DR.', 'Carrie', 'Madej', 100000);

SELECT * FROM T_EMPLOYEE;


Thanks for answering @SnowPro_Engineer I think in the example you provided INSERTED and UPDATED column are exactly the same, both of them will by add the current timestamp when we insert a new row, how about when we update a row?

When you update the row you need to manually update the UPDATED_TIMESTAMP and UPDATED_BY columns as opposed to an INSERT which will happen automatically due to the DEFAULT attributes. I hope that helps.

Not sure who formatted my SQL code but thank you very much - it looks beautiful now and I will be sure to use tildes in future - not sure how to access backticks on a UK keyboard. It looked great in Snowflake but then it lost the formatting on here. I am new to StackOverflow so please bear with me. :-)

Good answer from Suraj Ganiga above and thank you I learnt something new, however I prefer to add the auditing fields onto the table of interest for quicker access and to avoid joining onto the SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.TABLES every time.
